# adb install command is not working

Tags: android, eclipse, usb, adb

I am trying to install apk via usb is not installing.
Device is detected perfectly .but apk is not installing.

Even i tried with the following command.

```
D:\Softwares\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\platform-tools>adb install f:Fi
lth\Sample\bin\Sample.apk
4669 KB/s (277327 bytes in 0.058s)

D:\Softwares\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\platform-tools>
```

Comment: did you set the appropriate developer settings on the phone? you have to explicitly allow installing packages not from the app store on most phones.

Comment: also, you have to install the usb debugging tool in the sdk file under tools - execute that executable.

Comment: Two common causes of failure are that the application is already installed and you do not provide the re-install flag, or that the application is already installed *with a different signing certificate* in which case you will need to uninstall the existing version first.

Comment: it's working for other phone(iball andi 4.5q).but same command i given but it's not working on karbonn a18+ mobile.(rooted).

device is detected perfectly.i verified via ddms.
given command daemon started successfully.
is there any problem with rooted mobile?
help me to get rid out of this.

Answer (score 6):

First, check whether your device is connected or not. If connected, check there is only one device running i.e. mobile or emulator.

**Copy your apk file and paste inside the platform-tools folder**

```
D:\Softwares\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\platform-tools>
```

now shift+right click on the platform-tools folder -> Open command window here

Then check whether your adb is running successfully or not.Try these command to restart adb

```
 adb kill-server
 adb start-server
```

now you got the message "daemon started successfully"

now just use

```
adb install Sample.apk
```

Check out the image if you still have any problem.

[image]

Comment: Strange thing... When I run install command, it simply stays blank like waiting for something... But the device is rightly connected...